# How do I trim the "0." after I do modulo 1 on a double variable

Tags: c#

Hello everyone as the title say I want to trim the "0." after I do modulo 1 on a double variable

Example:

```
double Number;
Number = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());        //12.777
test = Number % 1;                                    //0.777
```

I want my output to be: 777
only using math with no
string trims and so...

Thank you all !!
and in c# please

Comment: you're outputting to screen. technically EVERYTHING has to be a string, because if you output that 0.777 as it really is stored internally, you'd get 8 randomish bytes of "noise"

Comment: If you want to keep this as numbers only (i.e. it's not meant for output), you will need to multiply by 1000 to get rid of the dot. And then, round.

Comment: Are `0.777` and `0.0777` supposed to be the same? Because without some sort of special string handling, they will be. 'trim the "0."' is not a mathematical operation done to rational, real, or floating point numbers, but something done to a decimal string.

Comment: @MrLister I know. It was an example to show that his idea doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: I think you need to explain why you want to do this using only "math", because mathematically this makes no sense. Like Tim mentioned, "0777" and "777" are numerically equivalent but "0.777" and "0.0777" are not.

Comment: He is trying to recreate the error in Office Space and make out like a bandit.

Answer (score 2):

That is just a formatting on the ToString. Take a look at all your options [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94.aspx)

How about

```
.ToString(".###");
```

Comment: That gives back 12.777

Comment: Are you doing a ToString on `Number` or `test`. It sounds like you are  using ToString on the wrong variable

Comment: it leaves the dot... and it isnt good if i read a bigger number like 12.7777777.....

Comment: Oops, sorry. but doing it on test gives '.777' not '777'

Comment: Just us a SubString to remove . after the fact It does work for larger numbers as you saw by it outputting 12.777

Answer (score 2):

Without using any string functions!

```
while(Math.Round(Number-(int)Number,1)!=1)
{
    Number=Number/0.1;
    if(Number-(int)Number==0)break;//To cover edge case like 0.1 or 0.9
}
```

**NOTE**: Number should be of `double` type!

Answer (score 1):

If I take your question literally, then you do not want the decimal point either, so `.ToString(".###")` will not get you what you want, unless you remove the first character (which is string manipulation, and you said you don't want that either).

If you want `777` in a numeric variable (not a string), then you can multiply your result by 1000, though I don't know if you'll always have exactly 3 digits after the decimal or not.

The easiest way really is just to use string manipulation. `ToString` the result without any formatting, then get the substring starting after the decimal. For example:

```
var x = (.777d).ToString();
var result = x.SubString(x.IndexOf('.') + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are certainly looking for this:-

```
.ToString(".###");
```

As correctly pointed by Marc in comments  you should have everything to be in a string, because if you output that 0.777 as it really is stored internally, you'd get 8 random bytes.

Something like this:-

```
var num = (.777d).ToString();
var result = num.SubString(num.IndexOf('.') + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The most generic way to do this would be:

```
using System.Globalization;


var provider = NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo;

var output = test.ToString(".###", provider)
             .Replace(provider.NumberDecimalSeparator, String.Empty);
```

You can also set the `NumberDecimalSeparator` on a custom `NumberFormatInfo`, but if you set it to empty it will throw the exception "Decimal separator cannot be the empty string."